# To bind mount my /dist folder in docker compose up

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

All the code for my app, including the docker-compose file is inside my work directory folder "store-front". Inside I have my /src and my /dist folder.

I would like to create a docker-compose file that bind mount /dist folder in my local host machine to the docker container.

What that docker-compose file look like?

My docker-compose file is:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - './postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"
  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
  web:
    build: .
    command: [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./dist
        target: /dist
    links:
      - postgres
    image: store-front-project
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    env_file:
      - .env

volumes:
  postgres:
```

And my dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY package*.json ./
COPY tsconfig.json ./
COPY nodemon.json ./

RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install

COPY . .
COPY database.json .
COPY .env .

EXPOSE 3000

ENTRYPOINT ["nodemon", "/dist/server.js"]  
CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:dev" ]
```

My directory is:

```
/
- docker-compose.yml
- .env
- tscofig.json
- database.json
- nodemon.json
- src/
  - server.ts
-dist/
 - server.js
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried already; what does your current `docker-compose.yml` file look like and what problems are you running into?  Do you actually need Docker, or is it enough to run some sort of HTTP server over the `./dist` directory on your host system?

Comment: What does your folder look like ? tree .

Comment: I edited the question and added what my folder looks like.

Comment: Im just trying to run a web server in a docker container with nodemon that watches changes in my server.js file inside my /dist folder

Comment: You might try running only the database and other prepackaged dependencies in Docker, and running `nodemon` on the host.  That would get you the advantages of having a prepackaged somewhat-disposable database, but avoid the complexities of trying to replace an image's code at run time.

Comment: So shall I avoid trying to create a web server docker image with live reload and keep the nodemon for my local server while having only the images of postgres and pgadmin?

I would like to learn anyway... it seems like it would help to get better ideas about servers

Comment: [Please refrain from asking the same question multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74100551/how-to-bind-mount-my-server-js-file-for-my-docker-server-container) --- What is the problem with the current approach?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml` sample :

- List item

```
version: '2.0'
services:
    dc_group_name:
        container_name: dc_container_name
        #  image: <IMAGE>:<TAG>
        image: dc_image_id_or_tag
        ports:
            - 16320:16320
            # - <LOCAL_PORT>:<CONTAINER_PORT>
        environment:
            LANG: "en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_ALL: "en_US.UTF-8"
            LC_TYPE: "en_US.UTF-8"
        volumes:
            - ..:/mnt/workspace            
            - /mnt/local_host/path:/mnt/docker-inside/path
            ## path_of_local_host: abs_path_of_docker_container
        command:
            - /mnt/workspace/_keep_alive.sh 
            ## run program script

## usage: 
### ./docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up -d
```

Comment: I am not familiar with your workspace and path. Could you please apply it with my example and my working directory? And why are you creating two volumes ? Thanks

Comment: The sample means docker-compose support volumn both relative path and absolute path to  docker container.   You should  change the settings by yourself.